# Trouble connecting a Subflow to a main flow

Tags: visual-workflow, subflow

I have a screen flow that displays Account fields dynamically based on the Type of account the user selects. The user then makes selections on the screen and saves the changes. I am trying to create an automation that would clear all of the user's previous selections if the Type of account is changed. I thought a subflow would be a workable solution, so I created a record-triggered flow (to be used as the sub-flow) with the AccountID variable available for input. When I try to call the record-triggered flow using the subflow element it is not populating in the 'Referenced Flow' search box. Trying to figure out why that is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subflow must be autolaunched type or screen flow type, not record-triggered type.  See [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_subflow.htm&type=5):

> Add a Subflow element to your flow. In the Referenced Flow field,
> search for an autolaunched or screen flow to configure.

Comment: Confusingly, some of my record triggered flows are marked as autolaunched in the list of flows. This seems to be because record triggered is a type of autolaunched. If there's no object listed in the triggering object column then it's a true autolaunched.